# toast setGravity is not working it show normal default toast

Tags: java, android-studio, toast, android-toast

i add the toast like this

```
     Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
     t.show();
```

it is not working it shows normal default toast.

Comment: Which Android version are you testing on? They put some restrictions on `Toast`s starting in 11: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#text-toast-api-changes.

Comment: i am testing on Android 10.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.